# In the console I can use items in JSON, through console.log they dont show

Tags: javascript, json, console.log

I parsed a CSV file to JSON then added my own headers for other strange reasons. So I have data that looks like this:

[image]

in my js file I have

> console.log(jsonData.theData[0].symbol);

and I get:

```
admin.js:46 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

It looks like 0 is defined to me, however when I just type in the browser console the same command in the js file I get good results.

[image]
I have tried

> JSON.stringify(jsonData.theData[0])

with the same error resulting.

Any idea why this isnt working?

js file below:

```
    var jsonData = {};
var theData = [];

document.getElementById("fileToRead").addEventListener("change",function() {
     var input = document.getElementById("fileToRead");

        for(var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++){
            var files = input.files[i];
            Papa.parse(files, {
            header:false,
            dynamictyping:true,
            complete:function(results){
                var input = results.data;
                input.forEach(function(input){
                    jsonData.theData = theData;

                    var singleEntry = {
                        "symbol"    : input[0],
                        "date"      : input[1],
                        "open"      : input[2],
                        "high"      : input[3],
                        "low"       : input[4],
                        "close"     : input[5],
                        "volume"    : input[6]
                        }

                    jsonData.theData.push(singleEntry);
                })
                //console.log (jsonData);
               // document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
                } // End Complete - Callback
            }); // End PapaParse
    } // End for loop
console.log(jsonData);
});
```

edit.................

I added some console.logs to it and received this....

[image]

Comment: Where exactly in the admin.js file do you call the `console.log()` function? I suspect you are calling the function in the wrong place where that particular variable is not defined.

Comment: I will edit with the code.

Comment: Did what I said helped? I mean does it make sense or helped you?

Comment: Are you sure about that? I get all of the data, all 7900ish lines.

Comment: You are right, I didn't realize javascript worked that way. Learned something new by misspeaking!

Answer (score 1):

Click on the little `i` icon. Its a race condition, your object is not getting loaded in time for your `console.log(jsonData.theData[0].symbol);`. Inspector is loading it for you after the fact

Comment: I see the little icon, so how can I get it to show after everything has been loaded and not before?

Answer (score 0):

When you call your

> console.log(jsonData.theData[0].symbol);

Are you sure that your jsonData is loaded ?

**Edit** *(after JS code updated)*

In your JS code, there is no `console.log(jsonData.theData[0].symbol);`... We can't see and understand your mistake.

Anyway,
as I said, even if your `console.log(jsonData);` is made at the end of the loop, it could be empty anyway because you load **your data asynchronously**

[source](http://papaparse.com/)

> Since file parsing is asynchronous, don't forget a callback.

So your jsonData could be empty (so, not loaded)